# Writing a complex .htaccess file in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My requirement

1. check for mobile or pc and redirect to correct URL.
2. If user comes directly to some internal page, he should be on that page only.
3. Old redirects should also work.

Request 1st comes to apache server where document root is mobile website. So here i have a .htaccess file where i have to do all the above things. And this is what i have written till now. And all redirection do not work properly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
/** Pc site settings **/
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!{android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile}" [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/abc/def/abc.html$ #http://www.pcsite.com/a/abc/abc.html [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.pcsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
/** Pc site settings - end**/  

/** mobile site settings **/
  RewriteRule web.config - [F,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)(device/[^/]+/)(min/.*)$ $1$3?_device=$2 [QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=min/.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_path=%1 [L,QSA]

/** mobile site settings - End**/
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Small question first : Did you restart apache?

Comment: yes i did restart apache. But still this is a change in .htacess file.